# Eclipse unable to find the Gatling simulation scripts

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, gatling

I'm able to run the Simulations on the command line and the Recorder on Eclipse but whenever I try to run Engine.scala on Eclipse I get the Output

"*There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in user-files/simulations*"

(which is actually a message valid only for the bundle as the simulations files should be in src\test\scala according to the documentation and the IDEPathHelper).

I already checked any similar problem on Stack Overflow and on the Gatling group but couldn't find a solution. I also put the simulations folder in different positions of the project but had no luck so far.

Here are the specs of the software I'm using:

- Eclipse IDE EE : Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- JDK : jdk1.8.0_201
- Scala IDE : 4.7.x
- Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna and newer) 1.5
- Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Juno 1.0.1)

Additional Info:

All simulations classes include `extends Simulation`
`JAVA_HOME` and `GATLING_HOME` are correctly set in Gatling.bat 
`ìo.gatling` in the pom.xml set to 3.0.3

I even tried to add this line to the `val props` of the Engine.scala 
`.sourcesDirectory(IDEPathHelper.mavenSourcesDirectory.toString)` as I don't actually see how is the project supposed to find the Simulations folder but it doesn't even compile.

Does anybody have any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

If you look in `IDEPathHelper.scala`, the mavenBinariesDirectory points to -> `projectRootDir/target/test-classes`

```
val mavenBinariesDirectory = mavenTargetDirectory / "test-classes"
```

Your Java build path may be set with default output folder `something/target/classes`.

Correct it to as shown in the image and give it a try.

[Java build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfjW3.png)